# webresponse cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using `WebRequest` and `WebResponse`, I'm able to post login information to an external site and receive the cookie in `Response.Cookies` and in my `CookieContainer`.  I know this is working because in the same procedure, I can request a different page and not be redirected to the login page.  This cookie is what allows me to stay on the site without logging in with each page view.

I'm now trying to add the cookie to the client's browser using `Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie)`;

However, it's only persisting until the end of the procedure.  Reload the page, and the cookie is no longer available.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at this answer, it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212713/grabbing-cookies-in-web-browser-control-wp7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cookies you receive from a `WebResponse` from an external site cannot be passed onto your own client's browser. This is because of the inherent security limitations of the cookie model: browsers do not support having one domain set cookies for another domain.

This may appear to work until the end of the current request since you are just reading from the `HttpCookieCollection` which you just added the cookie to. This collection will persist until the current HTTP request ends.

However, to be honest, I'm not sure how you're able to get this far at all since the the `System.Net.HttpWebResponse` and `CookieContainer` use `System.Net.Cookie`, while the `Response.Cookies` collection uses `System.Web.HttpCookie`.

Anyway, your best bet here is probably to store the value of the cookie you got in the `WebResponse` into your own cookie that you send to the browser. Then, on future requests, read your own cookie, construct a new `Cookie` for the external site, and add it to the `CookieContainer` manually.

Here is some pseudocode, assuming that the cookie the external site is looking for is named "sessionKey" and we use "myCookie" for the name the cookie we send to our client's browser:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var container = new CookieContainer();

    if (Request.Cookies["myCookie"] != null)
    {
         // browser has passed in "myCookie".
         // use this to create the "sessionKey" cookie to send.
         var cookie = new System.Net.Cookie("sessionKey",
             Request.Cookies["myCookie"].Value, "/", "external-site.com");

         container.Add(cookie);
    }

    HttpWebRequest request;
    HttpWebResponse response;

    // initialize the request.
    // ...

    // make sure we're using our cookie container.
    request.CookieContainer = container;

    // execute the request and get the response.
    response = request.GetResponse();

    // send a cookie, "myCookie", to the browser.
    // it will contain the value of the "sessionKey" cookie.
    Response.Cookies["myCookie"].Value = response.Cookies["sessionKey"].Value;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  you tipped me off as to why i wasn't seeing the cookie as well.  I was wondering why the cookie wasn't being set in Sharepoint and then i read this post and new i was in different zones.