# WP7 ListPicker control in development mode

Tags: windows-phone-7, listpicker

I am using the WP7 ListPicker control to display 7 items on the current form. I set the ItemCountThreshold="7" so all the items display in the current form like a drop down control would work.

This works well.

The problem I am having is that since I need the control to take up the entire Grid so that all the items display correctly and since the control is "brought to front", I can't click on any control positioned below the ListPicker while in development mode. When running the form, everything works. But in development mode, the only way to click on another control below the 
ListPicker is to send the ListPicker to back, then work on another control, then bring the ListPicker to front.

Is there anyway around this?

I have to have the ListPicker in front so that when the form runs and the ListPicker is opened, the ListPicker will open over top of the other controls. If the ListPicker is sent to back and the form is run, then when the ListPicker opens, the other controls bleed through the ListPicker.

Is there a property for the ListPicker to open over top of the other controls?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46xf4h0w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Grabbing Cookies in Web Browser Control - WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212713/grabbing-cookies-in-web-browser-control-wp7)

see this question and try to grab cookies as explained and check their value for your page if they are set or not. I hope I am right