# Web Request is a type and cannot be used as an expression

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, windows-phone

I am making an app for Windows Phone and since I need some login cookies that are saved in Web browser control, I am using the code from here: [Grabbing Cookies in Web Browser Control - WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212713/grabbing-cookies-in-web-browser-control-wp7) to create a HTTPWebRequest and get some JSON data for parsing but I am getting two errors on the last line of this snippet

```
 Dim browser = New WebBrowser()
    Dim brwhttp = GetType(WebRequestCreator).GetProperty("BrowserHttp")
    Dim requestFactory = TryCast(brwhttp.GetValue(Browser, Nothing), IWebRequestCreate)
    Dim uri = New Uri("some-url")
    Dim req = requestFactory.Create(uri)
    req.Method = "GET"
    req.BeginGetResponse(New AsyncCallback(request_CallBack), WebRequest)
```

(1). 'WebRequest' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.
 (2).  Delegate 'System.AsyncCallback' requires an 'AddressOf' expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its constructor.

How to fix?

UPDATE 1: Fixed Error (2) by adding 'Address Of' before 'request_CallBack' but Error (1) still remains.
UPDATE 2: Fixed all errors but not getting any response (empty). What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

THe problems are two do with the line `req.BeginGetResponse(New AsyncCallback(request_CallBack), WebRequest)` This has two problems.

1. VB.Net does not have true first class functions so you have to use the `AddressOf` operator the create a delegate. Also the compiler will infer the delegate type so you don't need the constructor
2. BeginGetResponse takes a state object as the second parameter not a type expression. This is whatever you need in the callback

so:

```
req.BeginGetResponse(AddressOf request_CallBack, Nothing)
```

If you need to pass a type to the request callback use

```
req.BeginGetResponse(AddressOf request_CallBack, GetType(WebRequest))
```

However this looks like a copying change and what you want may be

```
req.BeginGetResponse(AddressOf request_CallBack, req)
```

Comment: @user2141754 corrected unless you need to pass information to request_Callback

Comment: This is my request_Callback code:

`Private Sub request_Callback(asyncResult As IAsyncResult)
Dim webRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(asyncResult.AsyncState, HttpWebRequest)
Dim webResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult), HttpWebResponse)
Dim tempStream As New MemoryStream()
webResponse.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(tempStream)
Dim sr As New StreamReader(tempStream)
Dim resp As String = sr.ReadToEnd
MessageBox.Show(resp)
End Sub`

Throws error on line 1. Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But There's one more error, on last line: Invalid cross-thread access. An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: @user2141754 Try `Me.Invoke(addressof Messagebox.Show)` to execute it on the UI thread

Comment: Me.Invoke doesn't exist on WP apparently.

Comment: Sorry My mistake, I do mostly Windows forms programs try `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(addressof Messagebox.Show)` instead

Comment: Did. `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(AddressOf MessageBox.Show(resp))` throws error 'AddressOf' operand must be the name of a method (without parentheses).

Comment: use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(sub () MessageBox.Show(resp))`

Comment: That worked, but the response is empty. I am trying to read the response from http://api.quora.com/api/logged_in_user?fields=inbox,notifs,following,followers